# Error "java.util.Date does not take parameters" in Squeryl's where "clause"

Tags: scala, squeryl

I'm fairly new to Scala and currently using an ORM called Squeryl against our MySQL database.

What I'm trying to do is looking up plural records that fall within a time range.
For example, in plain SQL, I think it would be something like:

```
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE updated_at >= ? AND updated_at < ?
```

However, my Scala code to achieve similar behavior as below, gives me an error saying "java.util.Date does not take parameters" at the opening bracket in "from(records)"

```
    def getRecordsBetween(from:java.util.Date, til:java.util.Date):List[Record]
      transaction {
        from(records)(record =>
          where(
            record.updatedAt gte from and
            record.updatedAt lt til
          )
          select(record)
        ).toList
      }
    }
```

(where val records = tableRecord

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you try to surround the comparisons with parentheses, i.e., ``where((record.updatedAt gte from) and (record.updatedAt lt til))``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method parameters and methods are in the same namespace in Scala, so your `from` method parameter is "shadowing" the `from` method on the [`PrimitiveTypeMode`](http://squeryl.org/api/org/squeryl/PrimitiveTypeMode%24.html) (or `CustomTypeMode`) object that you brought into scope with a line like the following:

```
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
```

Just change the parameter name to `fromDate` or `start` or whatever and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! So it was rather an issue of my var/val naming than Squeryl's. Not sure why I didn't think of that... *facepalm*